# Writing single image to consecutive partitions using dd

Tags: filesystems, partition, backup, dd

Is it possible to write an image larger than the partition using dd? Supposing I had:

```
blah.img: 8GB

/dev/sda1: 3GB
/dev/sda2: 4GB
/dev/sda3: 4GB
...
```

Are consecutive partitions guaranteed to be laid out adjacently and without padding, such that I could expect this to precisely overwrite both /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3?

```
dd if=./blah.img of=/dev/sda2
```

And would that be the same as if I copied from the disks and concatenated?

```
dd "if=/dev/sda{2,3}" of=./blah.img
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition block devices (`/dev/sda2` etc.) won’t allow you to write beyond their limits, so you can’t write past the end of `/dev/sda2` through `/dev/sda2`.

You *could* overwrite multiple partitions by writing to the appropriate offset of the containing device (`/dev/sda`); however partitions *are not* guaranteed to be laid out on disk in their numeric order, without padding. `/dev/sda3` could point to disk blocks before `/dev/sda2`.

Reading `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` successively will only give you the data contained inside each partition, it’s not equivalent to reading from the start of `/dev/sda2` to the end of `/dev/sda3` (assuming `/dev/sda3` is laid out after `/dev/sda2` on disk).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know, thank you!